# Inconsistent result with use of time.perf_counter() in Python

Tags: python, windows, time

Here are two codes aiming to measure the time ellapsing to perform naive modular exponentiation and fast modular exponentiation in Python :

```
import time as t
T=t.perf_counter()
r=pow(777777,777777,10000)
T=t.perf_counter()-T
print(r,"Time rapid exp",T)
```

The time printed is around 1×10<sup>-5</sup>s and this seems to be correct. BUT :

```
import time as t
T=t.perf_counter()
r=(777777**777777)%10000
T=t.perf_counter()-T
print(r,"Time naive exp",T)
```

The time printed is around 1×10<sup>-6</sup>s and this seems to be really wrong as the code takes more than 1s to execute.

Does somebody know what is happening and how one could measure the correct value of execution time ?

Comment: You're dealing with such small times, is probably just noise. Anyway, you should use `timeit`

Comment: I used %timeit and the result is still inconsistent but a bit better :

    %timeit (777777**777777)%10000

Answer : 20.8 ns per loop (inconsistent)
Compiler time: 3.54 s (consistent)

    %timeit pow(777777,777777,10000)

Answer : 3.76 µs per loop (consistent)

Comment: Well maybe you're running into floating point imprecision, but I can't replicate this, on my system it takes > 10 seconds for the 2nd snippet

Comment: All calculations are performed on integers so that it can't be floating point imprecision.

But, I use Python on Windows. Are you using Linux or Unix ? This could be the reason for the inconsistency I observed and which you can't reproduce.

Comment: Which version of Python are using in Windows? It works for me in Windows CPython 3.5.2 (32-bit and 64-bit) and CPython 3.6.0 (64-bit). The 2nd printed time is about 500-1500 times the first.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4.3 (64 bit), iPython 4.

Comment: It also works for me in 64-bit 3.4.4. Try without IPython, just plain python.exe.

Comment: Doesn't work either for me with plain python.exe.
I'll come back on this subject after an upgrade of my Python distribution.
Thanks for your answers.